# imagemagick mogrify resize - loosing 3rd dimension

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick

I have alot of image files which are in the format of (height, width, 3). And I want to resize them to (98,98,3) specifically. So I resized sucessfully resized most images with the following command:

`mogrify -rezise 98x98\! $f`

But the weird thing is that for exactly one of my image folders it always resizes to only (98,98) and I really cannot see why or how to change this behaviour! The original image size was (256,346,3)

Comment: What does (256,346,3) mean? 3 channels? Perhaps the images that fail are 8-bit palette (single channel) color and not 24-bit 3-channel color. Also if your files are 24-bit color, but have 256 colors or less, Imagemagick tries to output the simplest format, which would be 8-bit color. You can try by adding -type truecolor to your command and see fi that works. It depends upon the image format whether it will respect that, PNG may not in mogrify. You may have to use `convert image.png -resize 98x98\! PNG24:image.png`. see https://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#type

Comment: Oh sorry those are the dimensions of my image! So yes, 3 channels. The weird thing, all the images are .jpg, I have several where all the images come from the same source and resizing works without a problem and the resized images still have 3 channels. It is literally just that one folder which is behaving like this, but I cannot understand why it would behave differently!

Comment: Um… I did notice a typo in your question's sample code. Are we sure that is not the problem? `rezise`

Comment: Post and example JPG that fails so we can experiment. You may need to zip it and post to some free hosting service so that it does not get changed. then put the URL here. What is your exact version of Imagemagick `convert -version` and the date associated with it. What is your platform? What is your version of libjpeg?  If not the current 90, then try upgrading. You can see the version from `convert -list format` at the end of the line starting with JPG or JPEG. Try `convert image.jpg -resize 98x98\! -type truecolor image.jpg`. Does that work?

Comment: I do not have the newest version, but turns out using `convert` works perfectly fine, whereas `mogrify` causes the error above. I will try and upload some example images a little later